# Recoger texto con caracteres especiales de un formulario e insertarlos en una base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Desearía recoger un texto con caracteres especiales `('´ñ)` de un formulario en `html`. Éste pasará a un `codigo.php` que se encargará de insertarlo en una base de datos `MySQL`.

El caso es que he intentado mil formas de hacerlo y no consigo que se inserte, ni que se recoja... y ya no sé que mas hacer.

**Código html:**

```
<head>
  <title></title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>

    <form action="codigo.php" method=POST name=Entrada enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="cad" maxlength="5" size="3"/>
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
        <input id=enviar type=submit value=Publicar />
    </form>
```

**Código php:**

```
$text=utf8_encode($_POST["text"]);
$cad=utf8_encode($_POST["cad"]);

echo $text." ".$cad; // Imprime sin problemas las variables

$servidor
$usuario
$pass
$bbdd

$conexion=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$pass,$bbdd) or die ("Error 505 NOT FOUND");

$sql="INSERT into datos ('texto','cadenas') VALUES ('$text','$cad')";
$tabla=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

**Base de datos:**

Tanto la base de datos como sus tablas están en `latin2_general_ci`.

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo y el error que te da

Comment: Editado con el código. Error no da ninguno, simplemente no lo inserta en la base de datos.

Comment: Porque no usas las codificación `UTF-8` ? tanto para tu html como para la BD. Además también podrías usar la función `htmlentities()`

Comment: Fue de las primeras cosas que intenté y no hubo manera...

Comment: ¿ Has probado con **mysqli_real_escape_string** ?
`$textoFinal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $text);  $cadFinal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $cad); $sql="INSERT into datos ('texto','cadenas') VALUES ('$textoFinal','$cadFinal')";`

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y no ha tenido efecto, sinceramente no sé que hago mal...

Comment: Podrías ponerme un texto de ejemplo que introduces para intentar reproducirlo ?

Comment: en `<textarea>` `prúeba pr'ueba prñueba` y en `<input>` `prue`

Comment: Agrego una respuesta con el código, probado y funcionando

Comment: He publicado una respuesta en la que expongo tu principal problema, inyectar directamente el contenido de las variables en el SQL sin usar consultas preparadas ni la función de escapado. El segundo problema que sufres es por culpa del cotejamiento `latin2_general_ci` (`iso-8859-2`) no soporta ni eñe ni otros símbolos de uso común en español.

Comment: He agregado a mi respuesta la manera de convertir todo a utf-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu cotejamiento es `latin2_general_ci` (`ISO 8859-2`, no soporta ni `ñ` ni `¡`) entonces te recomiendo que todo tu código trabaje con él y no uses ni `utf8_encode` ni `utf8_decode` ya que no tendrá ningún efecto:

```
<?php
/* Avisamos que el contenido está codificado en iso-8859-2 */
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-2');
/* Si estamos recibiendo el formulario insertamos el registro */
if (isset($_POST['cad'])) {
    /* Establecemos la conexión */
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $pass, $bbdd) or die("Error 505 NOT FOUND");
    /* Hacemos coincidir el juego de caracteres con el cotejo de la base de datos */
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'latin2');
    /* Preparamos la consulta */
    $consulta = mysqli_prepare($conexion, '
        INSERT into datos (texto, cadenas )
        VALUES (?, ?)
    ');
    if ($consulta === false) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
    /* Asignamos a cada ? un valor de tipo string */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta, 'ss',
        $_POST['cad'],
        $_POST['text']
    );
    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta) === false) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-2">
    <title>Página de prueba</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="Entrada" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="cad" maxlength="5" size="3" />
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
        <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Publicar" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

He agregado la forma correcta de para evitar un fallo SQL cuando se reciben caracteres que puedan cerrar la consulta (como el `'`) usando consultas preparadas. Con este código también evitarás problemas de [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

También he reforzado el código para mostrar el error que pueda provocar una consulta (en tu caso te estaba dando un error de sintaxis SQL que no estabas mostrando en ningún momento).

---

**Resumen y solución propuesta**

El principal problema que sufres es inyectar cadenas directamente a la consulta SQL, lo que provoca que si en ésta hay caracteres SQL (como el cierre de cadena `'`) la consulta SQL tenga error de sintaxis y no se ejecute.

Para solucionarlo usa consultas preparadas con [`mysqli_prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli-prepare). Si insistes en agregar cadenas directamente al SQL, al menos usa [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli-real-escape-string).

El segundo está relacionado con las cadenas que tienes de prueba. Por ejemplo, no existe forma de codificar `¡Caña! to'` (en `ISO 8859-15`) en el juego de caracteres `ISO 8859-2`, apareciendo en su lugar `ĄCańa! to'`.

En la cadena `'´ñ` de tu pregunta no existe el carácter `´` ni en `ISO-8859-2` ni en `ISO-8859-15`, por lo que será imposible almacenarla con dicho cotejamiento o juego de caracteres.

Para solucionarlo te recomiendo que cambies todo a `utf-8` (cotejamiento `utf8_general_ci`) y que tanto tus páginas como bases de datos, tablas, etc compartan el mismo juego de caracteres. Darás soporte a muchos más idiomas, incluidos emoticonos y símbolos (como ☀, ☎, ☘, ☺, etc), y no estarás limitado a sólo 256 caracteres (de los cuales sólo una pequeña porción son útiles en realidad).

Aquí tienes un enlace a la tabla de caracteres de [`ISO-8859-2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2), y aquí la de [`ISO-8859-15`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15). Podrás comprobar la limitación que tiene usar cualquiera de los dos.

**Conversión de la base de datos**

Deberás ejecutar las siguientes consultas SQL para cambiar el cotejamiento por defecto de la base de datos y de la tabla:

```
ALTER DATABASE nombre_de_tu_base_de_datos
  CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE datos
  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Ten en cuenta que pasar de prácticamente cualquier juego de caracteres a `utf-8` es posible, pero la conversión contraria (a `iso-8859-2` de vuelta, por ejemplo) podría fallar y haber pérdida de datos por usar caracteres que no se pudieran codificar a ese juego.

**Modificaciones en el HTML/PHP**

Una vez corregido el cotejamiento por defecto (o juego de caracteres) de la base de datos y el de la tabla, podrás cambiar el juego de caracteres de los archivos PHP (no todos los editores soportan esto último, te recomiendo `Atom`, `Notepad++`, etc) y hacer los siguientes cambios:

```
<?php
/* Ahora avisamos que el contenido está en UTF-8 */
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
/* Si estamos recibiendo el formulario insertamos el registro */
if (isset($_POST['cad'])) {
    /* Establecemos la conexión */
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $pass, $bbdd) or die("Error 505 NOT FOUND");
    /* Ahora debemos informar que todo irá en UTF-8 */
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');
    /* Preparamos la consulta, todo esto no cambia */
    $consulta = mysqli_prepare($conexion, '
        INSERT into datos (texto, cadenas )
        VALUES (?, ?)
    ');
    if ($consulta === false) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
    /* Asignamos a cada ? un valor de tipo string, tampoco cambia */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta, 'ss',
        $_POST['cad'],
        $_POST['text']
    );
    /* Ejecutamos la consulta igual que antes, sin cambios */
    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta) === false) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"><!-- Ahora debemos cambiar aquí el juego de caracteres -->
    <title>Página de prueba</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><!-- Y también aquí -->
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="Entrada" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="cad" maxlength="5" size="3" />
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
        <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Publicar" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Con estos cambios tendrás toda tu aplicación convertida a `utf-8` y, por lo tanto, soportarás prácticamente cualquier carácter de cualquier lengua o símbolo especial.

Comment: Perdona que no haya podido contestar antes. Te has currado una respuesta de 10. Tanto para latin2 como para UTF8. Te lo agradezco, has solventado mi problema y encima me has aclarado unas cuantas dudas que tenía, me servirá para futuras cosas que tengo pensadoo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, ha sido un placer :) Si tienes alguna duda sobre cualquier cosa de la respuesta no dudes en dejarme un comentario, y si tienes otra duda y creas una pregunta nueva déjame también un comentario para que le eche un vistazo lo antes posible.

Comment: La respuesta a la primera pregunta está más abajo en la explicación. Se tratan de consultas preparadas donde pones "?" luego usarás "bind_param" para colocar en ese lugar parámetros de diferentes tipos ("s" para string/cadenas, "i" para integer/enteros, "d" para double/decimales, "b" para blobs, etc, en el enlace que te pongo aparecen más detalles). Esa función corregirá cualquier problema con la cadena automáticamente (por ejemplo, escapar los caracteres como `'`).

Comment: A tu segunda pregunta te respondo que no es necesario usar `utf8_encode` ni similares porque tu código, el HTML y la base de datos están en el mismo juego de caracteres, por lo que no necesitas hacer conversión alguna.

Comment: muy bueno me has salvado, gracias.

Comment: Un placer haber sido de ayuda @DerlyPacheco

Answer (score 1):

Añadiendo la opción accept-charset="utf-8" en el formulario.

```
<form action="archivo.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: No me ha dado resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu `echo` te arroja correctamente tus datos quiere decir que tu `html` esta bien intenta cambiar la `BD` a

```
utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera me esta funcionando, tal como indicas que tienes la db:

```
 $text=utf8_encode($_POST["text"]);
 $cad=utf8_encode($_POST["cad"]);

 echo $text." ".$cad; // Imprime sin problemas las variables

 $servidor = '';
 $usuario  = '';
 $pass     = '';
 $bbdd     = '';

 $conexion=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$pass,$bbdd) or die ("Error 505 NOT FOUND");

 //mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');
 $textoFinal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $text); 
 $cadFinal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $cad);

 $sql="INSERT INTO datos ( texto , cadenas ) VALUES ( '{$textoFinal}' , '{$cadFinal}')";
 $tabla=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me gustaría saber cómo has solucionado la codificación del carácter `´` en `ISO-8859-2`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Me introduce los datos en la db pero no las `ñ` ni las comillas. ¿Como has solucionado eso?